# Different "margin-left" results with same browser in different devices

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to put an image (a hat) above the letter "u" in the word "blablablau".

The result I expect is that:

[image]

I solved this with this code:

```html
<img id="img-hat" src="hat.png">
<p id="title-bla">blablablau</p>
```

```css
#img-hat {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    position: absolute; 
    margin-left: 118px; 
    height: 23px; 
    width: 37px
}

#title-bla {
    margin-bottom: -5px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 170%; 
    margin-top: 2px; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif
}
```

The problem is that, using the SAME browser (like chrome) in different devices, I get different `margin-left` results in my `img-hat`.

Example: in my computer it shows correctly. In my laptop it shows correctly too. But, in another laptop (with same screen resolution), it shows the hat a little bit more to the right, like that:

[image]

And this behaviour continues in my cellphone and in another computer that I tested.

Why this happens and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this kind of issue I truly recommend you to use a CSS reset like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which will make browsers render all elements more consistently.

One way to get the result that you want is trying something like this:

```
<h1 class="title">Blumenau <i class="hat"></i></h1>
```

Use your icon/image with `position: absolute` within a parent element with `position: relative` so you can control more precisely where your icon should appear. You can change the icon position by change his top/right or bottom/left declarations.

```
/* Just to put away from the border to this example */
body {
    padding: 100px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
/*
    To avoid that margin and padding to be consider on the width and height set
*/
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
/*
    Parent
*/
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 32px;
}
/*
    Icon/image
*/
.hat{
    background: url('http://s23.postimg.org/os0nl4rrr/rsz_hat.png');        
    transform:rotate(15deg);
    top: -2px;
    right: -9px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 19px;
}
/**
 * Icon/image position
 */
.title i {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

See it in action on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txjwsq2b/7/).

Answer (score 10):

I'd prefer not to have the image in the HTML at all...it's styling so it should be in the CSS.

So, I use a span to wrap the letter to receive the hat, give it a class and apply the image as a background to a positioned pseudo-element.

By sizing everything in `em` the hat size will be dynamic to the text size.

```css
.title-bla {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}
.large {
  font-size: 72px;
}
.hat {
  position: relative;
}
.hat:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-image: url(http://b.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/christmas_surprise_four_in_one/png/128x128/santa_hat.png);
  background-size: cover;
  transform:rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<p class="title-bla">blablabla<span class="hat">u</span>
</p>

<p class="title-bla large">blablabla<span class="hat">u</span>
</p>
```

Then you can adjust either the margins or the positioning values to nudge it into place to suit...even rotate it to a jaunty angle. :)

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked horizontally (the hat is always above of the "u"). However, vertically I still have some differences between devices. In my computer it shows as I want but in my cellphone it shows the hat a little bit more down. Note: I changed the ".hat:after" to "top:7; left: -5;".

Comment: Here is an image of how it shows your own example in my cellphone: http://s22.postimg.org/g3w0v9jz5/Screenshot_2015_09_25_09_25_38.png. You can see that vertically the hat is more above.

Comment: I suspect that's a difference in default line-height among browser, try setting it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

First, you want to absolutely position from right, not left, because your letters may not be exactly the same in different devices.  Even with a web font, the displays vary slightly for each browser with letters.

Second, if you want it very exact then you need font-size and line-height in px or rems.  170% may be slightly different depending on the default font size for various devices.  Additionally, sometimes mobile devices adjust font size on short or long paragraphs.

This Fiddle should help: https://jsfiddle.net/cjc5myde/1/

```
#title-bla {
position:relative; top:-2px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom: -5px; 
font-weight: bold; 
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 28px; line-height:38px;  
}
#img-hat {
transform: rotate(25deg);
position: absolute; 
top:0; right:-25px; 
height: 23px; 
width: 37px
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put the `img` tag inside the `p` tag, it will automatically be placed at the end of the text. From there, you can just position the hat relative to its original position. You're probably going to need to tweak the left value a little.

```html
<p id="title-bla">blablablau<img id="img-hat" src="hat.png"></p>
```

```css
#img-hat {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    height: 23px;
    width: 37px
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, a `p` element will stretch full width. Needs to be `inline-block` preferably.

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference, the image comes right after the text it doesn't stick to the right side of the page

Comment: Yep, you're right. Had some different style going on.

Answer (score 0):

Different machines have different resolutions so their response in how they handle images and text with are displayed differently.  This is as expected.  Basically a browser will attempt to readjust the website to fit the viewing device.

That being said have you tried adding a z-index to your img-hat.  I personally do not use z-index often but in situations like this it could be helpful.  Another option have you tried relative positioning?

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default padding and margins that they resort to when our styles aren't applied. Sometimes, it's best if you drop all of that to 0.
Start your css file with

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

Check if it works

Comment: Yes I'm already doing that, but it doesn't work. Also I'm using the same browser always (chrome) both in my PC's, laptops and cellphone.